# Why are my duplicate items occuring twice in a row?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find out a list of all duplicate items in a `list`.

*My code:*

```
list=['see','eat','feel','see','eat']
i=0
j=0
l=[]

for i in range(len(list)-1):
    j=i+1
    for j in range(len(list)):
        if (list[i]==list[j]):
            l.append(list[i])

print(l)
```

*Expected output:*

```
['see', 'eat']
```

*Actual output:*

```
['see', 'see', 'eat', 'eat', 'feel', 'see', 'see']
```

The duplicates should only be there in the `list`. Where am I going wrong??

Comment: As a side note, `list` is a reserved keyword, and shouldn't be used as a variable name. Also, why are you doing `len(list)-1`? This only iterates over n-1 list items, so it doesn't get to the second `eat`

Comment: you are comparing each item with every items including it self. may be u want to change 2nd loop to ```for j in range(i+1, len(list)):```

Comment: @JammyDodger: he is checking whether the current value has duplicates later on in the list. He doesn't need to check that for the last value as there is no "later on the list". So that bit is actually correct imo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two lines:

```
j=i+1
for j in range(len(list)):
```

First you give some value to `j`, then in the for loop you let it loop over 0 up to len(list) and the value is forgotten. That wasn't what you meant.

Instead

```
for j in range(i+1, len(list)):
```

would do what you intended, I think.

But that still gives you problems if some value occurs, say, thrice.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Its funny cause I was just wondering how can you start a `for` loop from a specific index (as I am new to `python`),but now I get it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the `collections.Counter()` standard library class for a more efficient approach.

```py
import collections

lst = ['see','eat','feel','see','eat']
lst_counts = collections.Counter(lst)
duplicates = [value for (value, count) in lst_counts.items() if count > 1]

print(duplicates)
```

outputs

`['see', 'eat']`

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using list comprehension like below

```py
ls=['see','eat','feel','see','eat']

[ls[i] for i in range(len(ls)) for j in range(len(ls)) if (j>i and ls[i]==ls[j])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loops, so you get all combinations of pairs of two words.

Best, use only one loop, and keep track of duplicate elements:

```
seen = set()
duplicates = set()
for item in list:
    if item in seen:
        duplicates.add(item)
    else:
        seen.add(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
l=[]

for i in list:
    c=0
    for j in list:
        if i==j :
            c+=1
    if c!=1:
        flag=0
        for k in l:
            if k==i:
                flag=1
        if flag==0:
            l.append(i)
print(l)
```

in this code i used three loops 
1. for repetating each value to check weater it is duplicate or not 
2. for repetating each value and compare them togather . note repting values will whave value in c is 2 or more
3.to check weather the values stored in l are not repeating